# Understanding GROUP BY operator in Pig

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-pig

I have a table with the following fields:

id:chararray
date:string
country:string

I loaded this table in pig. My aim - to get the count of ids per country, monthwise. For example, this would be my required end result:

```
Country | Date1 | Date2 | Date 3| 

USA     | 140   |  160  | 200

China   | 120   |  210  | 150
```

The numbers represent the count of the ids, for each date, across all the countries.

I am not sure as to how I should use the GROUP BY operator. I first tried GROUP by (date) and then GROUP by (date, country). But I was not sure if this would give my required result as I am do not completely understand GROUP by single and multiple columns.

Any guidance, thoughts and explanation on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with GROUP BY operator in SQL, you should have a problem understanding GROUP BY operator in PIG.

To start with, I will do GROUP BY with COUNTRY and DATE

```
input = load '$input' USING AvroStorage(); -- or whatever LOAD storage function.
input2 = GROUP input BY Country, Date;
input3 = FOREACH input2 
            GENERATE 
                FLATTEN(group) AS (Country, Date), 
                COUNT(input) AS Count;

/*
input3 will look like below:

Country    Date       Count
USA        Date1      140
USA        Date2      160
USA        Date3      200
China      Date1      120
China      Date2      210
China      Date3      150

*/

-- Until this program is easy to write and to understand.
-- If you are fine with above schema, I would suggest to live with it.
-- If you really want to get the tabular format, it would involve lots of (31 to be precise = number of days in the month) JOINs on Country column.  
-- To give an idea about single JOIN:

input3a = FOREACH input3 GENERATE Country, Date, Count;
input4 = JOIN input3 BY Country, input3a BY Country;

input5 = FOREACH input4 
             GENERATE
                 input3::Country AS Country,
                 input3::Date AS Date1,
                 input3::Count AS Date1Count,
                 input3a::Date AS Date2,
                 input3a::Count AS Date2Count;
```

If you get the idea of how JOIN is used to gather 2 dates data together, you can understand why I suggested to live with earlier structure (input3).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Thank you for the explanation. It did help me understand better. However, I have a question. While generating input3, shouldn't it be COUNT(input2) instead of COUNT(input)? I am not sure though so please let me know if I am wrong and why I may be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: COUNT(input) is calculated while evaluating input3.